# Count, Sum, Average, Smallest, Largest

Tags: c, algorithm

We were assigned to write a program that reads a list of integers from the keyboard and creates the following information: the number of integers, the sum and the average of the integers, the smallest and largest integer. Thank you.

The input should be: "Enter numbers with < return > (99999 to stop)"

So far I have this code, but the answers I get are incorrect. It is only correct if I input 12345.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h>

 main()
 {
     int n,count=0,r,ave,small=0,large=0,sum=0;
     clrscr();
     printf("Enter numbers:");
     scanf("%i",&n);
     while(n!=0)
     {
            r=n%10;
            n/=10;
            sum=sum+r;
            count++;
            if(r>large)
            {
                 large=r;
            }
            if(r<small);
            {
             small=r;
            }
     }
     ave=sum/count;
     printf("Sum: %i\n",sum);
     printf("Total: %i\n",count);
     printf("Average:%i\n",ave);
     printf("Smallest:%i\n",small);
     printf("Largest:%i\n",large);
     getch();
}
```

Comment: This looks like C code and not C++. Also were you asked to take a bunch of numbers as input or perform the operations on one number's digits ? Furthermore, for minimum, assign the initial value to 10 and for maximum, initial value to -1, if you are operating on digits, since digits (of decimal number) are always between [0, 9]. However for a bunch of numbers, initialize minimum to INT_MAX and maximum to INT_MIN.

Comment: You don't take the sum, average or largest/smallest value of the actual input, you take it of all the *digits* in the single input.

Comment: For the average, you can implement an incremental approach as described [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106700/incremental-averageing).

Comment: You don't respect the specifications. The input is a list of integers (terminated with 99999), and you process a single string of digits.

Answer (score 2):

**Unintetional Coding Bug:**

`if(r<small);
{
    small=r;
}`

Here you putted a `;` at the end of condition check. So, in every iteration `small` is getting updated with the `r`.

**Initiation Problem:**
You initialized `small` with `0`. But it shouldn't be. It should be initialized with a greater value than the possible maximum value of input. In your case `10` should suffice.

**FYI:** 12345 input is working because the last value of `r` is `1` and `small` gets updated in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

try not to initalise the small to 0 , just keep it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write %d for integer.
And take small=9, then you get the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Amaya try this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<vector>
int OutputRemainder(int number)
{ 
   return number%10;
}
int OutputLargestNumber(std::vector<unsigned int> paramArr)
{
   int max=0;

   for(int i=0; i< paramArr.size(); i++)
   {

      if(paramArr.at>max)
      {
         max = paramArr.at;
      }
   }
  return max;
}
int OutputSmallestNumber(std::vector<unsigned int> paramArr)
{
   int min=paramArr.at(0);

   for(int i=0; i< paramArr.size(); i++)
   {

      if(paramArr.at<min)
      {
         min = paramArr.at;
      }
    }
   return min;
}
float AverageOfAllNumbers(std::vector<unsigned int> paramArr)
{
  float sum=0;
  float cond = paramArr.size();
  for(int i=0; i< cond; i++)
  {
     sum += paramArr.at;
  }
  return sum/paramArr.size();
}
int SumOfAllNumbers(std::vector<unsigned int> paramArr)
{
  int sum=0;
  for(int i=0; i< paramArr.size(); i++)
  {
     sum += paramArr.at;
  }
 return sum;
}



int main()
{
   unsigned int numberInput=0;
   unsigned int inputCount=0;
   float average=0;
   unsigned int smallestNumber=0;
   unsigned int largestNumber=0;
   unsigned int sum=0;
   std::vector<unsigned int> arr;

   printf("Enter numbers: ";
   scanf("%d",&numberInput);


   while(numberInput!=0)
   { 
      arr.push_back(OutputRemainder(numberInput));
      numberInput = numberInput/10;
   }

   largestNumber = OutputLargestNumber(arr);
   printf("\nLargest Number: %d", largestNumber);

   smallestNumber = OutputSmallestNumber(arr);
   printf("\nSmallest Number: %d", smallestNumber);

   average = AverageOfAllNumbers(arr);
   printf("\nAverage of Numbers: %f", average);

   sum = SumOfAllNumbers(arr);
   printf("\nSum of Numbers: %d", sum);

   inputCount = arr.size();
   printf("\nCount of Numbers: %d", inputCount);


   return 0;
```

}

Comment: The question is tagged C, not C++. Your code also contains multiple syntax and logic errors.